# Calculate the divide difference $f[1,2,3,4]$

Tags: numerical-methods

Let, $f:[0,4]\to \mathbb R$ be a three times continuously differentiable function. Then the value of the divide difference $f[1,2,3,4]$ is

(a) $\frac{f'(\xi)}{3}$ , for some $\xi \in (0,4)$

(b)  $\frac{f'(\xi)}{6}$ , for some $\xi \in (0,4)$

(c)  $\frac{f''(\xi)}{3}$ , for some $\xi \in (0,4)$

(d)  $\frac{f''(\xi)}{6}$ , for some $\xi \in (0,4)$.

From definition of divide difference I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)$ can be written in terms of divided differences as below:
$$
f_{3}(x)
= f[1] + f[1,2](x-1)+f[1,2,3](x-1)(x-2) + f[1,2,3,4](x-1)(x-2)(x-3).
$$

$f(x)$ is differentiable three times in the interval [0,4].
This follows with the following expression
\begin{align}
f'(x) & = f[1,2]+f[1,2,3](2x-3) + f[1,2,3,4](3x^2-12x+11), \\
f''(x) & = f[1,2,3](2) + f[1,2,3,4](6x-12), \\
f'''(x) & = f[1,2,3,4](6).
\end{align}
Thus for some $\varepsilon \in (0,4)$,
$$
f[1,2,3,4]
= \frac{f'''(\varepsilon)}{6}.
$$